# Can't install scimath in Python 2.7 to custom directory

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to install scimath 4.1.2 with pip 2.7.14 to a custom directory. There are two dependencies, that I have installed in a higher version than probably needed (but it's impossible to downgrade those):

- numpy==1.9.3
- matplotlib==2.0.2

Now, I'm getting the following error when trying to install scimath:

```
Processing /backup/pip/packages/scimath-4.1.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-QUsQtn/setup.py", line 9, in 
        import numpy.distutils.core
    ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-req-build-QUsQtn/
```

I'm not sure how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple and embarrassing: I forgot to export PYTHONPATH before running pip. With that variable, it was working.